# Using XML preferences, how can I make some of the `Preference`s use a different `SharedPreferences` instance?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using XML preferences and `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. I want to encrypt some of the values, such as passwords, but not others, such as theme settings. It seems that what I want to use would be [`EncryptedSharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences). But I'm not sure how to make it work with the UI. I see two issues:

- There seems to be no way to specify that this or this `Preference` should be using this or this `SharedPreference` instance;
- There seems to be no way of making `PreferenceFragmentCompat` use anything other than a single standard `SharedPreference` file, as set by methods such as `PreferenceManager#setSharedPreferencesName`.

The questions are,

- What's a way to make this work with minimal changes to the current codebase? And,
- What would be the ideal way to make this work if I'm willing to do a considerable rewrite?